# How to rotate a feature in OpenLayers2

Tags: openlayers-2, svg

I have an SVG image and I want to rotate it around itself. So I do the following:

```
var origin = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(vertices[0].x,vertices[0].y);            
feature.geometry.rotate(90 ,origin);
feature.layer.drawFeature(feature);
```

but nothing happens. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use :

```
layer.addFeatures(features)
```

Check this example :
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/styles-rotation.html

Answer (score 1):

dont try it with point, you cant understand your obj. rotate or not...this code is for linestring and works good.

```
var line = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                new OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString(points),null,null);
vector.addFeatures([line]);

var origin = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(10, 10);

line.geometry.rotate(30, origin);
line.layer.drawFeature(line);
```

i hope it helps you...